# Highlighting active menu item in blogger blogspot with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger, blogspot

I've got an issue with this javascript that I use to highlight active items in a navigation tab.
Everything's working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/gfkM4/148/ but in [blogger](http://innaplan.blogspot.co.at/index.html) it is not:

I added the class

```
.active_item {
    background:#EFEFEF;
}
```

to my template and put this script in front of the closing header tag

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

/* Function to add class active_item to navsub */

(function () {
    $('.navsub li').bind('click', function (e) {
        var el = $(this),
            list = $('.navsub').find('li');
        list.removeClass('active_item');
        el.addClass('active_item');
    });
}());

</script>

</head>
```

However, the class is not added as expected on blogger... 
Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your fiddle code is n't same as that in the website where you are doing a redirect on click of anchor tag.

Comment: You haven't an ajax website, so when you click on item in navsub, the event is lost. Edit each html page adding .active_item when you want active item.

Comment: @DonovanCharpin, you mean adding the  style for the class  active_item?

Comment: I see a static website, therefore it's not possible to retrieve the event. To solve the probleme easily. just add to li the active_item class on each page.

Comment: How would I add to li the active_item class on each page? Excuse me if I am ignorant.

Comment: Your menu is rewrite in each HTML page or not?

Comment: no,  i think the menu is only written in the html-template.

Comment: @DonovanCharpin, thanks - you pointed me into the right direction! I  was successcul without the script, by simply applying the style to the `navsub li` items with the appropiate selector `navsub li a[href="page.html"]`.

Comment: Good :). Pass the subject as resolved. Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..The problem was resolved without the use of javascript - see the comments.